# YQL XPath from a Yahoo Pipes Feed

Tags: loops, xpath, web-scraping, yql, yahoo-pipes

I have this situation where I need to get some data from a webpage and I'm trying to scrape it with Yahoo Pipes to make a rapid prototype. I divided the data with "Fetch Page", then I added a YQL query to a "Loop" so I can browse each result from the "Fetch Page" module and extract the data I need while keeping the grouping that came from the "Fetch Page" module.

The YQL query always sends an error when I add XPath to it asking for a URL.

So my question is that if it is possible to get XPath to work with the feed coming from the loop?

Comment: If you could share a link to the Pipe you're working on (or a minimal sample that illustrates the problem), someone might be more able to help debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CSV file stored on your domain to paste the grouping from the `fetch page` module. Query the CSV file using in a loop in Yahoo Pipes to get the data:

```
select * from html where url in (select col0 from csv where url="http://abdefg/foo.csv") and xpath="//title"
```